# Formula to add week ended date based on date value in different cell but add another week based on value in a separate cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created a formula where the week ended date is added to Column M if a date is entered into Column L and appears blank when Column L is blank.

```
=IF(L1<>"",L1+6-WEEKDAY(L1),"")
```

However, I would like to have an additional week added to Column M if there is any value entered into Column K in that same row.

```
=IF(L16<>"",L16+13-WEEKDAY(L16),"")
```

If column K is blank, column L has a date, column M will fill with the week ending date of the value in column L

If column K has any value, Column L has a date, column M will fill with the week ending date + 7 days (the following Friday)

I want Column M to appear blank when Column L is not used regardless of a value in Column K

The result should look like this:

[image: Snip]

Please let me know if this can be done all within one formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your original formula to add an additional 0 days if the value in K1 is blank and 7 days if it is not blank.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(L1),L1+6-WEEKDAY(L1)+IF(ISBLANK(K1),0,7),"")
```

Note that I have changed the test on L1 to check for a number. A text value in L1 would cause an error with your formula.